# SwiftUI iOS16 Table with optional string as keypath

Tags: swift, swiftui

How does one create a TableColumn for an optional property? Do i have to unwrap it in my model to make it an empty string if it is `nil`?

```swift
extension SomeObject {
    var someOptionalStringUnwrapped: String { return someOptionalString ?? "" }
}
```

```
Table(someObject) {
    TableColumn("One", value: \.someString)
    TableColumn("Two", value: \.someOptionalString) // <--shows error mentioned below
    TableColumn("Three", value: \.someOptionalStringUnwrapped) // <--compiles
}
```

> Key path value type 'String?' cannot be converted to contextual type 'String'

### Solution

For simple properties like strings & numbers the unwrap strategy seems to be easiest way to solve this (either a general extension like in the answer or per property like in the question). For more complicated UI one can always fall back to custom UI:

```
TableColumn("DEMO") { someObject in
    ...
    Text("\(someObject.someValue)")
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, unwrapping the optional in the model is one way you can solve this. Another solution would be to declare an extension on optionals, so you don't have to do this for every property like this.

```
// this could also be "where Wrapped: StringProtocol"
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var unwrapOrEmpty: Wrapped {
        self ?? ""
    }
}
```

```
TableColumn("Given Name", value: \.someOptionalString.unwrapOrEmpty)
```

Alternatively, create an extension on all `RangeReplaceableCollection`s, which `String` conforms to.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var unwrapOrEmpty: Wrapped {
        self ?? .init() // init() makes an empty collection
    }
}
```

A third way is to use another overload of `TableColumn`, like [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablecolumn/init(_:content:)-52cmd) which allows you to specify your own `Content` view.

```
init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (RowValue) -> Content)
```

You can write an extension on `TableColumn` which delegates to the above initialiser:

```
extension TableColumn where RowValue: Identifiable, Sort == Never, Content == Text, Label == Text {
    init(
        _ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey,
        value: KeyPath<RowValue, String?>
    ) {
        self.init(titleKey) { rowValue in
            Text(rowValue[keyPath: value] ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to write convenience Extensions, but this means unwrapping is the way to go. Thanks for the info

Comment: Wow, what a great answer. Also very helpful for many other optional cases, e.g. CoreData!